# C# array for finding all the 2's

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, numbers

Basically what I have to do is find a certain number, which in this case is 2, and see how many times I have that number in my program, I assumed that I would have to use a .GetValue(42) but it's not doing it right, the code I am using is

```
static int count2(int[] input)
{
    return input.GetValue(2);

}
```

input is from a separate method, but it contains the values that I'm working with which is

```
int [] input = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Comment: there are several ways to do this.. what have you tried beside what you have posted..? this is not that difficult..

Comment: I had messed around with a For(;;) code, but it didn't work at all, I'm really new and I've never seen this before.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you count specifically the number 2, or any number that contains the number 2.

For the later here's the easy way:

```
public int count2(int[] input) {
    int counter = 0;
    foreach(var i in input) {
        if (i.ToString().Contains("2"))
        {
            ++counter;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with LINQ
`input.Count(x=>x==2);`

Comment: That will count an input that is exactly 2, not sure if that's what the OP meant or not.

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.GetValue()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6swd8604(v=vs.110).aspx) "gets the value at the specified position in the one-dimensional Array" which is not what you want. (in your example it will return `3` because that's the value at index 2 of your array).

You want to count the number of times a specific item is *in* the array. That's a matter of looping and checking each item:

```
var counter = 0;
foreach(var item in input)
{
    if(item == 2)
    {
        counter++;
    }
}

return counter;
```

Answer (score 0):

to get a count do this

```
   int [] inputDupes = {1,2,3,4,5,2};
   var duplicates = inputDupes
           .Select(w => inputDupes.Contains(2))
           .GroupBy(q => q)
           .Where(gb => gb.Count() > 1)
           .Select(gb => gb.Key).Count();//returns an Int32 value
```

to see if there are duplicates of the number 2 then do the following

```
   int [] inputDupes = {1,2,3,4,5,2};
   var duplicates = inputDupes
           .Select(w => inputDupes.Contains(2))
           .GroupBy(q => q)
           .Where(gb => gb.Count() > 1)
           .Select(gb => gb.Key)
           .ToList(); //returns true | false
```

if you want to do this based on any number then create a method and pass a param in where .Contains() extension method is being called

> if you want to capture user input from Console you can do it this way as well

```
   int [] inputDupes = {1,2,3,4,5,2};
   Console.WriteLine("Enter a number to check for duplicates: ");
   string input = Console.ReadLine();
   int number;
   Int32.TryParse(input, out number);
   var dupeCount = inputDupes.Count(x => x == number);
   Console.WriteLine(dupeCount);
   Console.Read();
```

> Yields 2 for the duplicate Count

Comment: Why call `.AsEnumerable()` on an array which is already `IEnumerable`?

Answer (score 0):

```
static int count2(int[] input)
{
    return input.Count(i => i == 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Func like this:

```
public Func<int[], int, int> GetNumberCount =
  (numbers, numberToSearchFor) => 
  numbers.Count(num => num.Equals(numberToSearchFor));

...

var count = GetNumberCount(input, 2);
```

Gotta' love a Func :)